# Ember.js data from model doesn't being passed to the view when using ObjectController

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have this route:

```
App.BoardEditItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('boardItem', params.board_item_id);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('board-edit-item', {into: 'application'});
    }
});
```

and this controller:

```
App.BoardEditItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    pageTitle: 'Edit board item'
});
```

the boardItem model:

```
App.BoardItem = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    income: DS.attr('number'),
    outcome: DS.attr('number'),
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    itemType: DS.attr('string'),
    board: DS.belongsTo('Board'),
    boardId: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and this in the view:

```
{{input value=title}}
```

the title should come from the store, but it doesn't show...
unless I completely remove Ember.ObjectController.

any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you may want to consider refactoring your route there to just use the `boardItem` model. Depending on the model adapter it will be fetching the record again from the server when it already has it. `return this.modelFor('boardItem');` Would grab the model that the user is already looking at, but then you can display the edit form within an outlet and work on the same model. This is assuming your routes looks like `/board/item/2/edit/` or something like that. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It shouldn't make another call to the server when querying by id if it's already in the store, though I completely agree this.modelFor is way cleaner and simpler

Comment: unfortunately changing to what you suggest didn't work

Comment: will you show the boardEdit model definition?

Comment: updating question with the boarItem model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the reason for the weird behaviour was having

```
renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('board-edit-item', {into: 'application'});
}
```

present in the route.

does anyone know why it breaks it?

Answer (score 1):

`title` shouldn't be in quotes (assuming title is defined on your `boardItem` model).

```
 {{input value=title}}
```

Comment: it actually was without the quotes - I just forgot to remove it, after trying to modify it to be bindValue="title". updating my question.